# How can I add an ObservableCollection<Class<T>> use inheritance for T

Tags: c#, observablecollection

Say I have the following classes:

```
public class BaseConfig
{
}

public class SpecialConfig : BaseConfig
{
}
```

Then I have a generic class definition that will contain these:

```
public class ConfigList<T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : BaseConfig
{
}
```

Then I have another class where I want to have a collection of ConfigList objects:

```
public class ConfigurationManager
{
    private ObservableCollection<ConfigList<BaseConfig>> _configItems

    public ConfigurationManager()
    {
        _configItems = new ObservableCollection<ConfigList<BaseConfig>>();
    }

    public void AddConfigList(ConfigList<BaseConfig> configList)
    {
        _configItems.Add(configList);
    }
}
```

Then elsewhere in application code I have this:

```
ConfigurationManager _manager = new ConfigurationManager();
ConfigList<SpecialConfig> _configuration = new ConfigList<SpecialConfig>();
```

For some odd reason, I thought C# would allow the following due to inheritance, but it doesn't. What I want to know is how can I accomplish adding an object to a collection of a generic type of class like i'm doing below (This is surely a common problem people encounter and surely there's a simple pattern/solution to accomplish this):

```
_manager.AddConfigList(_configuration);
```

Comment: How do you get the list back from the `ConfigurationManager`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will not work this way, but luckily you can work around by taking advantage of [co-variance in generic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx), define one new co-variance interface:

```
public interface IConfigList<out T>
{
}
```

So your ConfigList inherits this interface:

```
public class ConfigList<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IConfigList<T> 
                                  where T : BaseConfig
{
}
```

And your `ConfigurationManager` uses `IConfigList` instead of `ConfigList`

```
public class ConfigurationManager
{
    private ObservableCollection<IConfigList<BaseConfig>> _configItems;

    public ConfigurationManager()
    {
        _configItems = new ObservableCollection<IConfigList<BaseConfig>>();
    }

    public void AddConfigList(IConfigList<BaseConfig> configList)
    {
        _configItems.Add(configList);
    }
}
```

Then it will work:

```
 ConfigurationManager _manager = new ConfigurationManager();
 IConfigList<BaseConfig> _configuration = new ConfigList<SpecialConfig>();

 _manager.AddConfigList(_configuration);
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew there had to be a way around this. Thanks for answering that quickly. It saves me a ton of time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to take advantage of generics [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx) to achieve this.